# Is there any method to convert seconds to LocalDateTime or ZonedDateTime object in java 8

Tags: java

I have a long value of seconds using which i want to build LocalDateTime object. I could not find direct method which can take long variable and build LocalDateTime object. Please help. I am using java 8.

Comment: What do you mean by *long value of seconds*? What are the seconds representing? Number of seconds since the start of day? Since Epoch? Since some other date/time?

Answer (score 4):

You can try :

```
long epochSecond = 10101010l; your number of second
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond, 0, null);
```

This will works only with the number of seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the OP is talking about number of seconds since the Epoch, which they did not state in the question.